# duplicate primary key import mysql table

Tags: import, duplicates, mysql

I have a mysql table file `students_r.sql` and I want to import this table to my mysql database using phpmyadmin interface.

However, when I choose the file and click Import I got following error:

```
Dump data for table `students_r` -- INSERT INTO `students_r` (`lastname`, `firstname`, `midname`) VALUES (....

    MySQL said:  
    #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

So does someone can help how to import the mysql table without an error?

Comment: Seems that the data you want to import violate a primary key constraint on the table students_r...

Comment: Please provide the table structure of the table students_r - but @hazard already made a guess...

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `students_r` (``, `lastname`, `firstname`, `midname`) VALUES ( ``,...)
```